# React Native ref is undefined until page reload

Tags: react-native, react-native-animatable

I am using refs to animate a View, but the refs are throwing an undefined error. However, if I comment-out my attempt to access the ref, load the page, un-comment the code, & reload the page, the animation works fine.

My code:

```
    export const AccountScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
        
          return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF', flex: 1 }}>
              <Animatable.View style={styles.container} ref={ref => {this.containerRef = ref}}>
              </Animatable.View>
            </SafeAreaView>
          )
      };

   launchOpenAnimation()
   function launchOpenAnimation () {
     this.containerRef.animate(appearContainerAnimation); //If I comment this out, reload, and un-comment, it works
   }
```

What can I do to fix this? It appears that the ref isn't defined at the time that my `launchOpenAnimation()` is executed, but that it is defined after, thus resulting in the code working if I comment it out, reload, un-comment, and reload again.

Comment: `AccountScreen ` is functional component there is no `this` keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first, your question is messed up between calls component and functional component, cuz there is no `this` in functional component. I'll convert them to function component using `useRef` and `useEffect`

In the first run this.containerRef have not be assign to ref of `Animatable` yet.

Try this

```js
export const AccountScreen = ({ navigation }) => { 
  const animateRef = useRef()
  useEffect(() =>{
     launchOpenAnimation()
     function launchOpenAnimation () {
       // add ? to make sure animate is called only when this.containerRef exists
     containerRef?.current.animate(appearContainerAnimation);
}    
  },[])
      
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF', flex: 1 }}>
      <Animatable.View style={styles.container} ref={ref => {
            ref.animate(appearContainerAnimation); // add this if you need to run when initial render run
            animateRef.current = ref
            }}>
      </Animatable.View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
};
```